# Positive semi-definite Matrix 3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I am trying to find the condition on $K$ under which the matrix
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
K-P &KWL^c\\
L^cWK & L^cWKWL^c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is positive semidefinite. Where $L^c$ is Laplacian Matrix, and $$
K=\begin{bmatrix}
k_1&0&0\\0&k_2&0\\0&0&k_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix}
p_1&0&0\\0&p_2&0\\0&0&p_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
are positive-definite.

PS: I have tried the following
$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
K-P &KWL^c\\
L^cWK & L^cWKWL^c
\end{bmatrix}}_{M}=
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
I &O\\
O & L^cW
\end{bmatrix}}_{N}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
K-P &K\\
K & K
\end{bmatrix}}_{S}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
I &O\\
O &WL^c
\end{bmatrix}}_{N^{\top}}
$$
If $S$ is positive definite then $M$ is positive-semidefinite. But $S$ can never be positive definite (One can verify this using schurs complement analysis). Moreover, this only a sufficient condition as $N$ is not a full rank Matrix.